# Microsoft Edge calls webservice 2 times

Tags: web-services, microsoft-edge

Below you can find the webservice code that is called two times when I open the webservice url with Microsoft Edge. No other browser I tested does this (Chrome, FF, IE11 - tested on different work stations). Can someone verify it and maybe has a workaround? I do have a byte[] which I want to return as PDF.

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadDocument()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        responseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(ms);

        responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        return responseMessage;
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi, please see my answer below. Thank you for raising my attention to this ticket again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the info from Microsoft that it´s a known issue. Please see the bug report here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/6734131/